# can't add more images to 3d slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel

this is my code

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    slides: 7
  },
  components: {
    'carousel-3d': Carousel3d.Carousel3d,
    'slide': Carousel3d.Slide
  }
})
```

```css
.carousel-3d-container figure {
  margin: 0;
}

.carousel-3d-container figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 12px;
  min-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://wlada.github.io/vue-carousel-3d/js/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://wlada.github.io/vue-carousel-3d/js/vue-carousel-3d.min.js"></script>
<div id="example">
  <carousel-3d :controls-visible="true" :clickable="false">
    <slide v-for="(slide, i) in slides" :index="i">
      <figure>
        <img src="images/IMG2.jpg">
      </figure>

    </slide>
  </carousel-3d>
</div>
```

In this my code works perfectly but i cant add more images to the slider only i can add a single image.how can i solve this.Iam trying to make a 3d slider the slider works perfectly with that singleimage but i need to add more images

Comment: where do you want to add images ? inside a `slide` or add another `slide` ?

Comment: inside the slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `data slides:1` and `:display:3` to have multiple slides

see more details here > `https://wlada.github.io/vue-carousel-3d/api/`

see snippet below with solution

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    slides: 1
  },
  components: {
    'carousel-3d': Carousel3d.Carousel3d,
    'slide': Carousel3d.Slide
  }
})
```

```css
.carousel-3d-container figure {
  margin: 0;
}

.carousel-3d-container figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://wlada.github.io/vue-carousel-3d/js/vue-carousel-3d.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://wlada.github.io/vue-carousel-3d/js/vue.js"></script>
<div id="example">
  <carousel-3d :controls-visible="true" :clickable="true" :display="3" :height="426">
    <slide v-for="(slide, i) in slides" :index="0">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
      </figure>
    </slide>
     <slide v-for="(slide, i) in slides" :index="1">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x250">
      </figure>
    </slide>
     <slide v-for="(slide, i) in slides" :index="2">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350">
      </figure>
    </slide>
  </carousel-3d>
</div>
```

Comment: i need only one slider with more images.in  my case slider is working.but  i can only add one image